# Make an excel cell mandatory, based on value of other 2 cells

Tags: excel, vba

So.. I've an excel where 2 consecutive cells can be marked with the same value (mostly Text), based on this 2 cells the value of the 3rd cell should be filled mandatorily by the user.

The range of cells can be different as I need to use the same snippet cross many excels.

Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

Many thanks! :)

Comment: **Give us an example.**

Comment: let's say A1 is "Hello" and B1 is also "Hello", then the user should enter something in C1.

To add, this can go down multiple rows..

Answer (score 0):

There's more then one way to skin a cat, but probably the easiest way to do it would be to include a vba sub which (on some trigger, like submitting) checks the value of cell 1 and 2 and IF that value is whatever you want to trigger on... if cell 3 is blank prompt the user to fill in box three.

```
IF Range("A1").Value == "Trigger" And Range("A2").Value == "Trigger" And Range("A3") == "" Then msgBox("You must fill in cell A3")
```

If you add a break statement like End Sub, the sheet can't continue until that cell is filled.

Comment: A more specific answer will help my understanding .. am a complete newbie to VB / Excel

Comment: If you see what Gary posted there... that's a more detailed version of this. Bit silly for me to type out what he posted in my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example for **A1**, **B1**, **C1**   enter the following event macro in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim A As Range, B As Range, C As Range
    Set A = Range("A1")
    Set B = Range("B1")
    Set C = Range("C1")
    If A <> "" And B <> "" And C = "" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            C.Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        MsgBox "please enter a value in cell C1"
    End If
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Gary,Thanks for the answer.
Can you please make it a bit more generic, let's say where I can have 4 rows, from A1 to A4 and B1 to B4?
or if we can add a while loop where it'll continue till it hits the last row?